# Thevenin Resistance by dropping independent sources

Tags: thevenin

[image]
Original Question

[image]
After dropping the sources

[image]
The solution

So my understanding is, once you drop the load resistor over a-b, the voltage at a and voltage at b are both 10 so the thevenin voltage is zero. From that, we can't use the Vthevenin/Inorton method of locating the Rthevenin so we have to drop the current and voltage sources. Voltage sources become a wire and current sources are breaks in the circuit. Why however, is the solution treating the two 10 ohm resistors as resistors in parallel? If it's because we're supposed to treat the bridge between a and b as a wire, why don't we treat all three resistors as if they're in parallel?

Comment: To be able to find \$Rth\$ seen from the a-b terminal we are connecting a "virtual voltage source" across a-b. To be able to see how the current will split in a circuit.   Look here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHrVg.png \$Rth = 10 \Omega||10 \Omega + 5 \Omega\$ https://tinyurl.com/y2dcoqyg

Comment: Ah. Forgot about the virtual voltage source... Thanks! I'll mark yours as resolved if you want to put it up as a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the circuit where you have removed the independent sources.

To find the Thevenin resistance you have to use your eyes and really LOOK through the terminals. Seriously, look into terminal a and redraw the circuit as you see it.

If you start at point \$a\$ you first encounter a node where you can take two paths. Both paths goes through a \$10\Omega\$ resistor. The paths meet again at the bottom node. The only way to go from there, is through the \$5\Omega\$ resistor, and then you end up at point \$b\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFoFSO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can you find the equivalent resistance between \$a\$ and \$b\$ from here?

Comment: Absolutely, I was too tunnel visioned on the fact that the 10 ohms were right next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

First, hello and welcome to Stack Exchange.
If you observe the diagram carefully, you will notice that the 2 10 ohm resistors are connected at the same pair of nodes and so they will always have the same voltage across themselves. However, the 5 ohm resistor is connected to this combination at only 1 node, so the current through the parallel combination is the same as the current in the 5 ohm resistor, so it is in series.

Answer (score 1):

Every time we drop the load resistor and compute for Thevevin Resistance, we should look the whole circuit from that perspective. It is done by putting an imaginary voltage source. For this example, this is how to do it. Pardon my effort to do the illustration with paint:

**Putting the Imaginary Voltage Source**
[image: Imaginary Voltage Source]

---

**Re-arranging of Circuitry for better view and analysis.**

[image: Re-arranging of circuitry for better view]

---

**Paralleling of two 10 ohms resistors. (Equal to 5 ohms)**
[image: Paralleling two 5 ohms resistors (can easily be seen after re-arranging)]

---

**Adding the 5 ohms result to 5 ohms connected in series.
Total Thevenin Resistance equals to *10 ohms*.**

[image: Total Thevenin Resistance after adding the result of paralleling to the 5 ohms in series]

---